# TensorFlow 2.2 using float16 executes only on CPU

Tags: tensorflow, floating-point, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/vcadillog/PPO-Mario-Bros-Tensorflow-2) as a starting point for one of my projects. Only modification I done so far is switching to OpenAI Gym Atari because I'm running it on Windows.

Problem I'm having is when I use `tf.keras.backend.set_floatx(tf.float16)` the code gets stuck executing on CPU. I also changed all the explicit casts throughout the code. The idea is to utilize the tensor cores on my GPU. This only happens with this code. All my other projects work fine.

I'm running it on TF 2.2. I tried removing `tf.function` annotations. I tried messing around with casts. For example leaving all the data in fp32 and using fp16 weights in the model. Nothing helped. Honestly I haven't tried much because I can't find any information on the problem and have no idea where to start debugging. There is no errors and everything works fine, except it runs on CPU instead of GPU. The only difference is in the mess that TF spews out when initializing I get this message:

```
W tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_device.cc:398] XLA_GPU and XLA_CPU devices are deprecated and will be removed in subsequent releases. Instead, use either @tf.function(experimental_compile=True) for must-compile semantics, or run with TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_auto_jit=2 for auto-clustering best-effort compilation.
```

I tried both options proposed in the message and nothing happened.

I really need this to work. Not just for the memory and performance optimizations but part of my project is benchmarking the difference between the two.

Any help would be appreciated or at least if someone could point me in the direction where to look for the information.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) directives? It could be that there is no fp16 kernel implementation for some operation (I haven't tried fp16 myself so I don't really know if this is common).

Comment: @jdehesa I just did. Nothing changed. Thank you for the suggestion.